# A scalar with memory, or how to correctly `tie`

Tags: raku

This is my attempt to solve Challenge #2 of the [weekly](https://perlweeklychallenge.org/blog/perl-weekly-challenge-027/).

The challenge is very vague, so I decided to try to implement a scalar value with a memory. It's possible my understanding of how containers should work is flawed, but what I really don't understand, is, why `say self.VAR.WHAT` is a `Proxy` and not a `HistoryProxy`, even when I explicitly say so.

```
class HistoryProxy is Proxy
{
    has @!history;
    method HISTORY() { @!history };
    method SAVE( $value ) { @!history.push($value) }
}

sub historic(::T $type, $value) {
    my T $c-value = $value;
    return-rw HistoryProxy.new(
        FETCH => method () { $c-value },
        STORE => method (T $new-value) {
            say self.VAR.WHAT;         # Why is this "Proxy" and not "HistoryProxy"?
            self.VAR.SAVE( $c-value ); # Why does this not work?
            $c-value = $new-value;
        }
    );
}

my $a := historic(Int, 10);
$a = 12;
$a = 14;
say $a.VAR.HISTORY; #should print [10, 12]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not help you get the functionality you want, but it does answer your specific questions for now:

> say self.VAR.WHAT;         # Why is this "Proxy" and not "HistoryProxy"?

I think this is because the `Proxy` class is currently not set up to be subclassed.  Its `new` method basically does a `Proxy.new` instead of a `self.new`, so it misses the subclassing.  Looking into that now.

> self.VAR.SAVE( $c-value ); # Why does this not work?

`self` is **always** decontainerized.  So you're always seeing the underlying value.  If you want to have the actual object, you will need to change the signature of the `method`, e.g.:

```
STORE => method (\SELF: T $new-value) {
```

and then use:

```
 SELF.VAR
```

But since the object isn't actually blessed as the subclass, this won't help you much anyway.

UPDATE: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/pull/3196 should allow subclassing of `Proxy` objects in the future.

UPDATE: with https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/d00674b31c this Pull Request got merged.  It should become available in the 2019.11 Rakudo compiler release.

Comment: Very nice. Liz++. Do you have a separate branch for this? If I write a test suite, can you run it? Then I could submit it as a "future" solution to the weekly challenge

Comment: It was in the "subclass-proxy" branch: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/tree/subclass-proxy

Comment: Let me know where your tests are, and I will run / add them to roast.  Meanwhile I've added some basic tests with https://github.com/perl6/roast/commit/bf7d0fbe51

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again Liz for adressing this so quickly. However, as i wrote on Github, while the subclassing works now, it seems to be impossible to initialize attributes of the subclass. This is fine for know, I can solve this with the `get-position` method.

Is this because `Proxy` is not a "proper" class, or am I overlooking something?

```
use Test;

class Scalar::History::Proxy is Proxy
{
    has @!history;
    has $!position = 0; # The assignment gets ignored ...

    # ... so do these

    submethod TWEAK( *@args )
    {
        say "Why oh why?";
    }

    submethod BUILD( *@args )
    {
        say "Do we never get called";
    }

    method get-position( \SELF: )
    {
        $!position // @!history.elems
    }

    method current-value( \SELF: )
    {
        @!history[ SELF.get-position ]
    }

    method get-history( \SELF: Bool :$all = False )
    {
        my $to-index = $all ?? @!history.elems - 1 !! SELF.get-position;
        @!history[ ^$to-index ].Array
    }

    method reset-history( \SELF: )
    {
        @!history = ();
        $!position = 0;
    }

    method forward-history( \SELF: $steps )
    {
        $!position = SELF.get-position + $steps;
        $!position = @!history.elems - 1
            if $!position >= @!history.elems;
        $!position;
    }

    method rewind-history( \SELF: $steps )
    {
        $!position = SELF.get-position - $steps;
        $!position = 0
            if $!position < 0;
        $!position;
    }

    method store-value( \SELF: $new-value, $register-duplicates )
    {
        # Forget stuff after rewind
        if @!history.elems > SELF.get-position + 1
        {
            @!history.splice( SELF.get-position + 1 );
        }

        if !($new-value eqv SELF.current-value) || $register-duplicates
        {
            @!history.push( $new-value );
            $!position = @!history.elems - 1;
        }
    }
}

class Scalar::History
{
    method create( $value, ::T $type = Any, Bool :$register-duplicates = False )
    {
        return-rw Scalar::History::Proxy.new(
            FETCH => method ( \SELF: ) {
                SELF.current-value() },
            STORE => method ( \SELF: T $new-value ) {
                SELF.store-value( $new-value, $register-duplicates ); }
        ) = $value;
    }
}
```

This passes all the tests I have

```
use Scalar::History;

use Test;

subtest 'untyped' =>
{
    plan 2;

    my $untyped := Scalar::History.create("a");
    my $sub = sub foo() { * };
    my $rx  = rx/x/;

    $untyped = $sub;
    $untyped = $rx;
    $untyped = 42;

    ok( $untyped == 42, "Current value is correct" );
    is-deeply( $untyped.VAR.get-history, ["a", $sub, $rx], "History is correct" );
}

subtest 'typed' =>
{
    plan 3;

    my $typed := Scalar::History.create("a", Str);
    $typed = "b";
    $typed = "42";

    ok( $typed == "42", "Current value is correct" );
    is-deeply( $typed.VAR.get-history, ["a", "b"], "History is correct" );
    dies-ok( { $typed = 2; }, "Cannot assign invalid type" );
}

subtest 'duplicates' =>
{
    plan 2;

    my $with-duplicates := Scalar::History.create( "a", Str, :register-duplicates(True) );
    $with-duplicates = "a";
    $with-duplicates = "a";
    is-deeply( $with-duplicates.VAR.get-history, ["a", "a"], "duplicates get registered" );

    my $no-duplicates := Scalar::History.create( "a", Str );
    $no-duplicates = "a";
    $no-duplicates = "a";
    is-deeply( $no-duplicates.VAR.get-history, [], "duplicates get ignored" );
}

subtest 'position/forward/backward' =>
{
    plan 8;
    my Int $int := Scalar::History.create(10, Int);
    #say $int.VAR.get-position;
    $int = 100 ;
    $int = 1000 ;
    ok( $int.VAR.get-position == 2, "current position is 2 after 3 assignments" );
    $int.VAR.rewind-history(2);
    ok( $int == 10, "current value is correct after rewind" );
    $int.VAR.forward-history(1);
    ok( $int == 100, "current value is correct after forward" );
    $int.VAR.rewind-history(Inf);
    ok( $int == 10, "current value equals start value after rewind to infinity" );
    $int.VAR.forward-history(Inf);
    ok( $int == 1000, "current value equals last known value after forward to infinity" );

    $int.VAR.rewind-history(2);
    is-deeply( $int.VAR.get-history, [], "history empty after rewind" );
    is-deeply( $int.VAR.get-history(:all), [10, 100], "but still there if needed" );
    $int = 101;
    $int = 1001;
    is-deeply( $int.VAR.get-history, [10, 101], "history gets truncated after rewind and assign" );
}

subtest 'behaviour' =>
{
    plan 2;

    sub add-one( Int $v ) { return $v + 1 }

    my Int $int := Scalar::History.create(1, Int);
    $int++;
    $int = $int + 1;
    $int = add-one( $int );
    $int = 42;

    is-deeply( $int.VAR.get-history, [1,2,3,4], "historic Int behaves like normal Int" ); # probably testing the language here, but  meh
    $int.VAR.reset-history();
    is-deeply( $int.VAR.get-history(:all), [], "history can be reset" );
}

done-testing;
```

Comment: I've been trying to make `Proxy` a "normal" class, but the results have been not so good.  Somewhere, this introduces an infinite recursion that eats memory at 1+ GB / sec on my machine.

Comment: I don't really see a way out of this, other then creating a specific `new` method and using a `TWEAK` method to set additional parameters: `    class A is Proxy {
        has $.position;

        method new(:&FETCH!, :&STORE!, *%_) is raw {
            my $self := self.Proxy::new(:&FETCH,:&STORE);
            $self.VAR.TWEAK(|%_);
            $self
        }

        method TWEAK(:$!position = 42 --> Nil) { }
    }
`